# If statement not returning string

Tags: android, if-statement, android-studio

Hello i have small problem with android studio.

I have made simple code that checks if user has inserted string with http:// if not then add http:// to string.

Here is part of my code:

```
    if (!host.contains("http://")) {
        String playlistUrl = "http://" + host + "/test.m3u";
    }else{
        String playlistUrl = host + "/test.m3u";
    }                
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(playlistUrl));
```

Android Studio drops me an error on last line (**cannot resolve symbol playlistUrl**)

```
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(playlistUrl));
```

But why? If statement should return string playlistUrl....

Comment: Your `String` is scoped inside the `if` statement blocks. Declare it outside of the `if` and set it's value inside the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the variable inside of the `if ... else` statement - it means it won't be visible outside.
You can implement it like this:

```
String playlistUrl;
if (...) {
     playlistUrl = ...;
}
else {
     playlistUrl = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare playlistUrl outside the if-else construct:

```
String playlistUrl;
if (!host.contains("http://")) {
   playlistUrl = "http://" + host + "/test.m3u";
} else{
   playlistUrl = host + "/test.m3u";
}                
intent.setData(Uri.parse(playlistUrl));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it this way your not using the same variable by redeclaring it

```
String playlistUrl = "";
if (!host.contains("http://")) {
     "http://" + host + "/test.m3u";
}else{
    playlistUrl = host + "/test.m3u";
}                
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(playlistUrl));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare and instantiate your var playListUrl outside the if statement. The reason for that is that the compiler only translates to bytecode without evaluating expressions.